# Do these symmetrical looking B field problems have the obvious answer?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I am struggling with two questions whose answers both appear to be trivially zero by symmetry arguments, when I was expecting more derivation to be required.

[wires in B fields http://epweb2.ph.bham.ac.uk/user/newson/img/currents.001.png](http://epweb2.ph.bham.ac.uk/user/newson/img/currents.001.png)

Problem A),

> An infinitely long wire lies on the z axis and an infintely long cylindrical conducting shell centred on the z axis surrounds it. There is a current +I flowing in the positive z direction in the wire, and a uniformly distributed current -I flowing in the negative z direction in the shell. What is the net magnetic force acting on the wire from the shell?

In this case, I think the B field at the centre of the circle is zero by symmetry: every infinitesimal segment of the outer shell has a corresponding segment on the opposite side producing a B field in the opposite direction. If there is no B field, there is force.

Problem B),

> A long conducting wire carrying a DC current I1 is surrounded by a circular current loop carrying a current I2. The wire is perpendicular to the plane of the circular loop. What is the net force acting on the straight wire due to the magnetic field from the circular current?

Here, I think that the B field due to the circular loop is parallel to the wire passing through it (we derived its magnitude in a previous part of the question and it seems to be pretty standard, e.g. [hyperphysics derivation](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html)). Since the force on a current in a B field is given by $F = I \vec{l} \times \vec{B}$, I think the force must be zero ($\vec{l}$ and $\vec{B}$ are paralell).

The question goes on to ask:

> If the current in the straight wire were to increase with a rate of 100 A/s, what would be the induced emf along the path of the circular loop?

This still seems to be trivially zero becase $\Phi  = \int \int \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{A} = 0$, so $d\Phi / dt$ is always zero.

I am confused because these were not presented as questions with simple answers not requiring any maths. Have I missed something?

Comment: I got hold of the solutions to part B) and the answer was indeed zero, so I was being unnecessarily worried.